# Pandas Webscraping Errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to webscrape websites for tables using pandas and I get this error for one of the links.

Here's a snippet of what causes the crash:

```
import pandas as pd
website_df = pd.read_html("https://ballotpedia.org/Roger_Wicker")
print(website_df)
```

Below is the error I get, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 700, in _next_line
    line = self._check_comments([self.data[self.pos]])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 385, in _infer_columns
    line = self._next_line()
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 713, in _next_line
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\legislators-current.py", line 15, in <module>
    website_df = pd.read_html("https://ballotpedia.org/Roger_Wicker")
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1205, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1011, in _parse
    df = _data_to_frame(data=table, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 890, in _data_to_frame
    with TextParser(body, header=header, **kwargs) as tp:
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1876, in TextParser
    return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1442, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1753, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 122, in __init__
    ) = self._infer_columns()
  File "C:\Users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 395, in _infer_columns
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Passed header=[1,2], len of 2, but only 2 lines in file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `header=0`. You're going to get a lot of dataframes, but you can parse them to get what you need.

```
website_df = pd.read_html("https://ballotpedia.org/Roger_Wicker", header=0)
```

Comment: Every website is different and it's probably going to be a manual effort unless you know a pattern you're looking for in the data. You can gain greater control with BeautifulSoup to find patterns in the html